# Store player's inventory

Tags: java, bukkit

How can I store a player's inventory, clear it, and then return it to the stored version?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use a [`HashMap`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/HashMap.html) to store the contents of all of the player's inventories and armor

```
Map<UUID, ItemStack[]> items = new HashMap<UUID, ItemStack[]>();
Map<UUID, ItemStack[]> armor = new HashMap<UUID, ItemStack[]>();
```

You could then store the player's inventory contents in the HashMap by using

```
UUID uuid = player.getUniqueId();

ItemStack[] contents = player.getInventory().getContents();
ItemStack[] armorContents = player.getInventory().getArmorContents();

items.put(uuid, contents);
armor.put(uuid, armorContents);
```

And then you could clear the player's inventory and armor by doing

```
player.getInventory().clear();

player.getInventory().setHelmet(null);
player.getInventory().setChestplate(null);
player.getInventory().setLeggings(null);
player.getInventory().setBoots(null);
```

To restore the inventory and amor, you could simply use

```
UUID uuid = player.getUniqueId();

ItemStack[] contents = items.get(uuid);
ItemStack[] armorContents = armor.get(uuid);

player.getInventory().setContents(contents);
player.getInventory().setArmorContents(armorContents);
```

So, you could have code that looks something like this

```
Map<UUID, ItemStack[]> items = new HashMap<UUID, ItemStack[]>();
Map<UUID, ItemStack[]> armor = new HashMap<UUID, ItemStack[]>();

public void storeAndClearInventory(Player player){
    UUID uuid = player.getUniqueId();

    ItemStack[] contents = player.getInventory().getContents();
    ItemStack[] armorContents = player.getInventory().getArmorContents();

    items.put(uuid, contents);
    armor.put(uuid, armorContents);

    player.getInventory().clear();

    player.getInventory().setHelmet(null);
    player.getInventory().setChestplate(null);
    player.getInventory().setLeggings(null);
    player.getInventory().setBoots(null);
}

public void restoreInventory(Player player){
    UUID uuid = player.getUniqueId();

    ItemStack[] contents = items.get(uuid);
    ItemStack[] armorContents = armor.get(uuid);

    if(contents != null){
        player.getInventory().setContents(contents);
    }
    else{//if the player has no inventory contents, clear their inventory
        player.getInventory().clear();
    }

    if(armorContents != null){
        player.getInventory().setArmorContents(armorContents);
    }
    else{//if the player has no armor, set the armor to null
        player.getInventory().setHelmet(null);
        player.getInventory().setChestplate(null);
        player.getInventory().setLeggings(null);
        player.getInventory().setBoots(null);
    }
}
```

Then you could just call `storeAndClearInventory(Player)` when you want to store the player's inventory, as well as clear it, and call `restoreInventory(Player)` when you want to restore the player's inventory to it's original state.

Comment: I tried that but it throws an exception because the item cannot be null!

Comment: @L3n it can should be able to be null... What version of bukkit are you using?

Comment: I'm using 1.7.2 craftbukkit..

Comment: @L3n Are you talking about the `player.getInventory().setHelmet(null)`?

Comment: No I'm talking about the player.getInventory().setContents(contents); and player.getInventory().setArmorContents(armorContents)

Comment: Thanks!It started working :)

Answer (score 1):

If you want to temporarily save the player's inventory, you could get the contents of their inventory (both the regular contents and the armor I assume?) and put them in some kind of list. You might also have to save the slot number for each ItemStack/item, in which case you might want to use a HashMap. To clear the player's inventory after you have saved the contents use `player.getInventory().clear()`. You can then later add the items again with `player.getInventory.setItem(slot, item)`.

If you want to make sure the inventory is saved even when the plugin is reloaded or the server is shut down, you need to turn the contents of the inventory into a string (serialize it) and save it to a file (Bukkit has stuff for this built in so that all the item metadata is preserved). Let me know if you need more information on this, I can write out more detailed code for any of these methods. There might be an easier way to copy the contents of an entire inventory temporarily and then use `player.getInventory().setContents(contents)`.